# How to get general spot instances pricing history

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, spot-instances

I would like to get spot instances pricing history for different regions and instances.

I found how to get my own [requests pricing history](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/using-spot-instances-history.html)

and found how to get the [current spot instances pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/spot/instance-advisor/) in the spot instance advisor

But can't find how to get the general history for all instance types and regions. How can I do that? preferably something that is ready for download, or in Python code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`describe_spot_price_history()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_spot_price_history):

> Describes the Spot price history.
>
> When you specify a start and end time, this operation returns the prices of the instance types within the time range that you specified and the time when the price changed. The price is valid within the time period that you specified; the response merely indicates the last time that the price changed.

Please note that since March 2018, Spot Prices are relatively stable. Previously, when capacity was required, AWS increase the spot price. Now, however, the Spot Price tends to stay the same but capacity is still recovered when needed. It means that higher bids do not impact the spot price.

For details, see: [New Amazon EC2 Spot pricing model: Simplified purchasing without bidding and fewer interruptions | AWS Compute Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/new-amazon-ec2-spot-pricing/)

As a result, the Spot Price History is not particularly interesting any more. The [Spot Instance Advisor](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/spot/instance-advisor/) is just as good a source of information to determine the likelihood of having spot instances taken away.